# ZSH (O-M-Z + powerlevel9k) + glyphs + console only (Ubuntu server edition): How to get all 3 working?

Tags: zsh, theme, oh-my-zsh

So I have installed ZSH + oh-my-zsh + powerlevel9k on my Ubuntu server edition.

While it's working including the colors (I used darkorange background to display current user), I cannot get the glyphs to work. In place of the home folder icon ([image]) when I'm on the user home folder, all I see is a triangle.

Can someone please advice how this can be done?

Thanks

Comment: You say Manjaro server edition, but the title says Ubuntu server edition. Which is it?

Comment: @0xSheepdog edited. got confused as I was just trrying out Manjaro architect.

Answer (score 0):

In order for the glyphs to display properly, you have to make sure that a Powerline font has been installed and that your console has been configured to use that font. The Powerline [installation instructions page](https://github.com/bhilburn/powerlevel9k/wiki/Install-Instructions#step-2-install-a-powerline-font) gives four ways to achieve this:

1. Install Powerline Fonts
2. Use a Programmer Font
3. Install Awesome-Powerline Fonts
4. Install Nerd-Fonts

The Powerline installation page further mentions:

> If Powerlevel9k is not working properly, it is almost always the case that the fonts were not properly installed, or you have not configured your terminal to use a Powerline-patched font.

Answer (score 0):

Most importantly, you need to follow the [installation instructions](https://github.com/Powerlevel9k/powerlevel9k/wiki/Install-Instructions#option-2-install-for-oh-my-zsh) for oh-my-zsh; not Ubuntu or other OS.

After that, set you `.zshrc` like below

```
# POWERLEVEL9K Setting
POWERLEVEL9K_MODE='nerdfont-complete'
POWERLEVEL9K_LEFT_PROMPT_ELEMENTS=(dir vcs)

# Set name of the theme to load --- if set to "random", it will
# load a random theme each time oh-my-zsh is loaded, in which case,
# to know which specific one was loaded, run: echo $RANDOM_THEME
# See https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/wiki/Themes
# ZSH_THEME="robbyrussell"
ZSH_THEME="powerlevel9k/powerlevel9k"
```